# QT Creator integration with Physx

Tags: qt, physx

Is there any way to integrate Qt and Physx so i can use Physx inside Qt Creator?

Comment: if not i'm gonna have to do the physx part of my project under Visual Studio ... but later how can i use the QT creator made UI to be my project's interface for the visual studio (physx) project?

Comment: I don't use Qt Creator myself, but am I right in saying that it uses mingw? If I recall correctly, mingw is not supported. But I'm not 100% sure. Therefor a comment and not an answer.

Comment: You can perfectly well use the Visual Studio Compiler (2008 or 2010, any edition) or the Windows SDK. It's just not part of the normal SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately PhysX is compiled against the `/MT` (static run-time version), while Qt MSVC uses `/MD`. Meaning you will have to build a Qt MSVC static build with `/MT`. Even if you get it to run using Qt's shared version you will run into the following warning and possible [problems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(VS.71).aspx):

`defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs...`

This stackoverflow answer will help you get you started for a qt static build: [How to build Qt 4.8/5.2 statically under VS2012, using the static MSVC runtime, with Windows XP support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862989)

To use the PhysX library with Qt MSVC (MinGW is not compatible with PhysX), here's an example qmake configuration.

```
PHYSX = /path/to/physx/library

INCLUDEPATH += $${PHYSX}/Include
LIBS += -L$${PHYSX}/Lib/win64

LIBS += \
    -lPhysX3CharacterKinematic_x64 \
    -lPhysX3_x64 \
    -lPhysX3Common_x64 \
    -lPhysX3Cooking_x64 \
    -lPhysX3Extensions \
    -lPhysX3Vehicle \
    -lPhysXProfileSDK \
    -lPhysXVisualDebuggerSDK \
    -lPxTask
```