# How to build Qt 4.8/5.2 statically under VS2012, using the static MSVC runtime, with Windows XP support?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012, qt4, qt5

I'd like to make a completely static build of Qt 4.8/5.2 under VS2012 - including static runtime libraries, and targeting Windows XP systems. This is not supported out-of-the-box by Qt, since even the static build of Qt uses the dynamically linked MSVC runtime.

This is to be a canonical question that provides the knowledge necessary to successfully build Qt meeting those requirements.

Comment: Hi, it seems a bit weird you've closed my question as duplicate, when in fact my question came 3 years before yours. If anything you should be closing yours.

Comment: @this.lau_ It's not a matter of who was first :)

Comment: You write your own (duplicate) question, you write your own answers to it, then you go around closing questions that were there before yours. There's a bit of a conflict of interest here, isn't it?

Answer (score 9):

### Qt 5.2

Assuming that the environment was prepared for XP targeting, and relevant XP-targeting `qt5xp.patch` and the bug fix `qt5fixes.patch`  available - both from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21840683/1329652), we have to do the following:

1. Create a separate `win32-msvc2012-static` and `win32-msvc2012-static-xp` qmake specs by copying them from `qtbase/mkspecs/win32-msvc2012` and `qtbase/mkspecs/win32-msvc2012-xp`, respectively.
2. Modify the qmake specs.
3. Teach configure and qmake makefile about the new qmake specs.
4. Force bootstrap of `configure.exe` by creating an empty `.gitignore` file in `qtbase`.
5. If you're configuring Qt with a `-prefix` so that the installation and build directories are separate, you must **apply the patch for [QTBUG-32519](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32519)** - at least until that bug gets fixed.

The following batch file does the complete job. At the moment, webkit building is disabled for static Qt builds.

```
:: Assume that we're in an equivalent of C:\Qt prefix
@set PREFIX=%~dp0
:: Qt sources
@set QT=%PREFIX%..\5.2.1-src
:: Patch file(s)
@set SRC=%PREFIX%
@set SPEC=win32-msvc2012
@if not exist "%QT%\qt.pro" ( echo Qt source folder expected in %QT%>&2 & exit /b 1 )
::
@patch --forward --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt5fixes.rej --input=%SRC%\qt5fixes.patch
::
@echo > %QT%\qtbase\.gitignore
@mkdir %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp
@copy %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%\qplatformdefs.h %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp
@copy %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%\qmake.conf %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp
@patch --forward --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt5xp.rej --input=%SRC%\qt5xp.patch
::
@mkdir %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static
@copy %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%\qplatformdefs.h %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static
@copy %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%\qmake.conf %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static
@mkdir %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static-xp
@copy %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp\qplatformdefs.h %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static-xp
@copy %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp\qmake.conf %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static-xp
@patch --forward --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt5static.rej --input=%SRC%\qt5static.patch
```

To **undo** the changes to the Qt source, run the following, with variables set as above:

```
@patch --reverse --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt5static-unfix.rej --input=%SRC%\qt5static.patch
@del %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static\qplatformdefs.h
@del %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static\qmake.conf
@rmdir %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static
@del %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static-xp\qplatformdefs.h
@del %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static-xp\qmake.conf
@rmdir %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static-xp
::
@patch --reverse --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt5xp-unfix.rej --input=%SRC%\qt5xp.patch
@del %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp\qplatformdefs.h
@del %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp\qmake.conf
@rmdir %QT%\qtbase\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp
@del %QT%\qtbase\.gitignore
::
@patch --reverse --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt5fixes-unfix.rej --input=%SRC%\qt5fixes.patch
```

The build is then performed by executing

```
configure -static -platform win32-msvc2012-static-xp (or win32-msvc2012-static)
jom (or nmake)
jom install (if doing the build separate from the installation directory)
```

```
# qt5static.patch
# Static MSVC Runtime Support for Qt 5.2
#
# Build qmake with XP targeting.
--- qtbase/qmake/Makefile.win32 2014-02-20 12:28:23.316380600 -0500
+++ qtbase/qmake/Makefile.win32 2014-02-20 12:29:07.396008900 -0500
@@ -42,7 +42,7 @@
               -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_COMPRESS \
               -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM \
               -DUNICODE -DQT_CRYPTOGRAPHICHASH_ONLY_SHA1 -DQT_JSON_READONLY
-!if "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-xp"
+!if "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-xp" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-static-xp"
 CFLAGS_BARE = $(CFLAGS_BARE) -D_USING_V110_SDK71_
 !endif
 CFLAGS   = -Yuqmake_pch.h -FIqmake_pch.h -Fpqmake_pch.pch $(CFLAGS_BARE) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CPPFLAGS)
# Add support for static qmake specs.
--- qtbase/qmake/Makefile.win32 2014-02-01 22:37:30.000000000 -0500
+++ qtbase/qmake/Makefile.win32 2014-02-17 16:21:09.329949100 -0500
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-!IF "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc.net" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2002" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2003" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2005" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2008" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2010" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-xp" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2013" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-icc"
+!IF "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc.net" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2002" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2003" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2005" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2008" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2010" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-static" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-static-xp" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-xp" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2013" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-icc"
 
 !if "$(SOURCE_PATH)" == ""
 SOURCE_PATH = ..

# Set static runtime.
--- qtbase/mkspecs/win32-msvc2012-static/qmake.conf 2014-02-17 23:01:29.965440300 -0500
+++ qtbase/mkspecs/win32-msvc2012-static/qmake.conf 2014-02-17 23:05:51.630568400 -0500
@@ -24,9 +24,9 @@
 QMAKE_CFLAGS            = -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON    = -W3
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_OFF   = -W0
-QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -O2 -MD
-QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO += -O2 -MD -Zi
-QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG      = -Zi -MDd
+QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -O2 -MT
+QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO += -O2 -MT -Zi -d2Zi+
+QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG      = -Zi -MTd -d2Zi+
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_YACC       =
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_LTCG       = -GL
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_MP         = -MP
# Set static runtime.
--- qtbase/mkspecs/win32-msvc2012-static-xp/qmake.conf  2014-02-17 23:01:29.965440300 -0500
+++ qtbase/mkspecs/win32-msvc2012-static-xp/qmake.conf  2014-02-17 23:05:51.630568400 -0500
@@ -24,9 +24,9 @@
 QMAKE_CFLAGS            = -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON    = -W3
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_OFF   = -W0
-QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -O2 -MD
-QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO += -O2 -MD -Zi
-QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG      = -Zi -MDd
+QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -O2 -MT
+QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO += -O2 -MT -Zi -d2Zi+
+QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG      = -Zi -MTd -d2Zi+
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_YACC       =
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_LTCG       = -GL
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_MP         = -MP
```

Answer (score 1):

### Qt 4.8

Assuming that the environment was prepared for XP targeting, and relevant XP-targeting `qt4xp.patch` and the bug fix `qt4fixes.patch`  available - both from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21917612/1329652), the following script does the job:

```
:: Assume that we're in an equivalent of C:\Qt prefix
@set PREFIX=%~dp0
:: Qt sources
@set QT=%PREFIX%..\4.8.5-src
:: Patch file(s)
@set SRC=%PREFIX%
@set SPEC=win32-msvc2012
@if not exist "%QT%\projects.pro" ( echo Qt source folder expected in %QT%>&2 & exit /b 1 )
::
@patch --forward --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt4fixes.rej --input=%SRC%\qt4fixes.patch
::
@mkdir %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp
@copy %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%\qplatformdefs.h %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp
@copy %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%\qmake.conf %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp
@patch --forward --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt4xp.rej --input=%SRC%\qt4xp.patch
::
@mkdir %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static
@copy %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%\qplatformdefs.h %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static
@copy %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%\qmake.conf %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static
@mkdir %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static-xp
@copy %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp\qplatformdefs.h %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static-xp
@copy %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp\qmake.conf %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static-xp
@patch --forward --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt4static.rej --input=%SRC%\qt4static.patch
```

To **undo** the changes to the Qt source, run the following, with variables set as above:

```
@patch --reverse --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt4static-unfix.rej --input=%SRC%\qt4static.patch
@del %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static\qplatformdefs.h
@del %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static\qmake.conf
@rmdir %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static
@del %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static-xp\qplatformdefs.h
@del %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static-xp\qmake.conf
@rmdir %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-static-xp
::
@patch --reverse --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt4xp-unfix.rej --input=%SRC%\qt4xp.patch
@del %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp\qplatformdefs.h
@del %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp\qmake.conf
@rmdir %QT%\mkspecs\%SPEC%-xp
::
@patch --reverse --directory=%QT% -p0 --global-reject-file=%SRC%\qt4fixes-unfix.rej --input=%SRC%\qt4fixes.patch
```

The build is then performed by executing

```
configure -static -platform win32-msvc2012-static-xp (or win32-msvc2012-static)
jom (or nmake)
```

```
# qt4static.patch
# Static MSVC Runtime Support for Qt 4.8
#
# Build configure with XP targeting
--- tools/configure/configure.pro   2014-02-20 10:00:29.840317000 -0500
+++ tools/configure/configure.pro   2014-02-20 10:03:06.674999600 -0500
@@ -4,7 +4,7 @@
 CONFIG   += console flat stl rtti_off
 CONFIG   -= moc qt
 DEFINES  = UNICODE QT_NODLL QT_NO_CODECS QT_NO_TEXTCODEC QT_NO_UNICODETABLES QT_LITE_COMPONENT QT_NO_STL QT_NO_COMPRESS QT_NO_THREAD QT_NO_QOBJECT QT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
-win32-msvc2012-xp: DEFINES += _USING_V110_SDK71_
+win32-msvc2012-xp|win32-msvc2012-static-xp: DEFINES += _USING_V110_SDK71_
 DEFINES  += QT_BOOTSTRAPPED
 
 win32 : LIBS += -lole32 -ladvapi32
# Add support for static qmake specs.
--- qmake/Makefile.win32    2013-06-07 09:17:02.000000000 -0400
+++ qmake/Makefile.win32    2014-02-20 09:31:51.090426700 -0500
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-!IF "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc.net" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2002" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2003" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2005" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2008" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2010" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-xp" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-icc"
+!IF "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc.net" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2002" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2003" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2005" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2008" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2010" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-xp" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-static" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-static-xp" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-icc"
 
 !if "$(SOURCE_PATH)" == ""
 SOURCE_PATH = ..
@@ -42,9 +42,9 @@
               -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -DUNICODE -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_NO_THREAD \
               -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED \
               -DQLIBRARYINFO_EPOCROOT
-!if "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-xp"
-CFLAGS_BARE = $(CFLAGS_BARE) -D_USING_V110_SDK71_
-!endif
+!if "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-xp" || "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2012-static-xp"
+CFLAGS_BARE = $(CFLAGS_BARE) -D_USING_V110_SDK71_
+!endif
 CFLAGS   = -Yuqmake_pch.h -FIqmake_pch.h -Fpqmake_pch.pch $(CFLAGS_BARE) $(CFLAGS)
 
 CXXFLAGS_BARE = $(CFLAGS_BARE)
# Set static runtime
--- mkspecs/win32-msvc2012-static/qmake.conf    2013-06-07 09:17:00.000000000 -0400
+++ mkspecs/win32-msvc2012-static/qmake.conf    2014-02-17 16:17:38.831119700 -0500
@@ -19,9 +19,9 @@
 QMAKE_CFLAGS            = -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t-
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON    = -W3
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_OFF   = -W0
-QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -O2 -MD
-QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO += -O2 -MD -Zi
-QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG      = -Zi -MDd
+QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -O2 -MT
+QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO += -O2 -MT -Zi -d2Zi+
+QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG      = -Zi -MTd -d2Zi+
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_YACC       =
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_LTCG       = -GL
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_MP         = -MP
# Set static runtime
--- mkspecs/win32-msvc2012-static-xp/qmake.conf 2013-06-07 09:17:00.000000000 -0400
+++ mkspecs/win32-msvc2012-static-xp/qmake.conf 2014-02-17 16:17:38.831119700 -0500
@@ -19,9 +19,9 @@
 QMAKE_CFLAGS            = -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t-
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON    = -W3
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_OFF   = -W0
-QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -O2 -MD
-QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO += -O2 -MD -Zi
-QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG      = -Zi -MDd
+QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -O2 -MT
+QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO += -O2 -MT -Zi -d2Zi+
+QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG      = -Zi -MTd -d2Zi+
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_YACC       =
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_LTCG       = -GL
 QMAKE_CFLAGS_MP         = -MP
```