# Qt 5.3.1 application error: Could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"

Tags: windows, qt, deployment, mingw, qt5

Precompiled Qt 5.3.1 with dynamic libraries, MinGW 32, Windows 8.1 x64

The deployed application cannot start on another computer giving the error:

Could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploy Qt app on win7 32-bit - works (and compiles) on Win7 x64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490869/deploy-qt-app-on-win7-32-bit-works-and-compiles-on-win7-x64)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a Qt Program without Qt itself being installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793363/how-to-run-a-qt-program-without-qt-itself-being-installed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by copying DLL from Qt's folder to ../MyApp/platforms/qwindows.dll.

Note: there is no "plugins" directory in path