# Qt - Could not find or load platform plugin "windows" - but it's right there! - dynamic build

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll

Error message:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows".

Reinstalling the application may fix the problem.
```

I've done a lot of searching and none of the solutions I've found worked.

I've followed this ["Deploy an App on Windows](https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows#Initial_deployment_.28Quick_and_dirty.29) - even the quick and dirty method failed. 
I have the `/platforms/qwindows.dll` [in my app root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25012347/qt-5-3-1-application-error-could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-windo).
I've used the dependancy walker app depend.exe we all know and love

```
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
```

Frankly I don't understand this... language barrier? It says that there are DLLs missing, `DCOMP.dll`, `API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0-.dll`, `API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT -ERROR-L1-1-0, -L1-1-0, -ROBUFFER-L1-1-0, -STRING-L1-1-0.DLL and API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-l1-1-0.dll`, but they are nowhere to be found. Similarily named dlls are included in kernel.dll and MSVCRT.dll. It also mentions `IESHIMS.dll`, but including it doesn't make a difference.

I have following dlls in my folder:

- /platforms/qwindows.dll
- icuin53.dll
- icudt53.dll
- icuuc53.dll
- libEGL.dll (even though my app doesn't use it)
- libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
- libopencv_core2410.dll
- libopencv_highgui2410.dll
- libopencv_imgproc2410.dll
- libstdc++-6.dll
- IEShims.dll
- libwinpthread-1.dll
- Qt5Core.dll
- Qt5Gui.dll
- Qt5Widgets.dll

Copied from `C:\Qt\5.4.0\5.4\mingw491_32`

There's an identical problem with the debug version of the exe, that has *d.dll libraries with it.

I am using Qt 5.4.0 and Mingw32 4.9.1 on Windows 7 64-bit.

The app obviously compiles and runs on my netbook, every other PC gives me the error, however I MUST distribute it. When I change C:\Qt to a different folder name, my netbook also produces the error.

Strange thing is, few versions of the app earlier, there wasn't any kind of problem. I've added a ton of code since then, but I don't remember anything that'd use a different library.

What could possibly be the issue?

Comment: Represent please some type or message error

Comment: @t3ft3l--i it's in the title. I'll add the full message, but temporarily I'm on a 1ghz netbook so it might take a while...

Comment: If you are runnin indebug you may need qwindowsd.dll

Comment: @GPPK it's the release version of the exe. Additionally, I've created a second directory with the debug version and *d.dll libraries

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the libraries. The problem was with the code. There was **one line** missing from the main.cpp, line that isn't included by default, but should be the first line of main() function.

**QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath("./");**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath("./"); //this goddamn line right here
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You can also put this into /etc/qt.conf in your resource file if.